# Proguard: how to avoid name conflict with obfuscated library class names?

Tags: proguard, conflict

Proguard: how to avoid name conflict with obfuscated library class names? e.g.,

A proguarded library jar contains class

```
com.mycompany.a.a.c
```

Proguard uses the same name for obfuscating a new class without checking library, e.g.

```
com.mycompany.foo.bar.ClassA -> com.mycompany.a.a.c
```

causes name conflict.

Solutions:

How to tell proguard to keep package prefix `com.mycompany.foo`? or rename package prefix

```
com.mycompany.foo -> com.mycompany.aa
```

to prevent name conflict.